# Auto return type of template and ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, visual-studio-2019, template-argument-deduction

I have an overloaded template function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto overMax(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;

    return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT overMax(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;

    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
auto a = overMax(4, 7.2); // uses first template
auto b = overMax<double>(4, 7.2); // uses second template
```

everything works perfect, but

```
auto c = overMax<int>(4, 7.2); // error
```

causes ambiguous call.

Why is it so with **int**, and OK which other types?

Comment: I think ….... The way the compiler sees it, is: with `int`, are you specifying the `typename RT` or the `typename T1`? Since `4` is also an `int`, it could be either. With `double`, `4` doesn't _directly_ match the type `double`, so the second overload is preferred.

Comment: This looks a bit dodgy to me because you're sort of overloading on the return type but with templates that have different amount of parameters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`RT` is non deducible, so when not providing it, only `template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto overMax(T1 a, T2 b)` can be called.

When you (partially) provide one template argument, both methods are viable,

but depending of argument, one can be a better candidate:

- For `auto b = overMax<double>(4, 7.2); // uses second template`

  Both `overMax<double, int, double>` and `overMax<double, double>` are viable.
  But `overMax<double, int, double>` is exact match
  whereas `overMax<double, double>` requires `int` to `double` conversion.
- For `auto c = overMax<int>(4, 7.2); // Ambiguous call`

  Both `overMax<int, int, double>` and `overMax<int, double>` are viable.
  But neither is a better match or more specialized, so the call is ambiguous.

Comment: why are neither of them a better much? Am I right that in the fist case _overMax<int>(4, 7.2);_ would cause conversion of _7.2_ to _int_. And in the second case the returned result, which is initially _double_, would be converted to _int_ due to explicit _<int>_ ?

Comment: @amplifier: `overMax<int>(4, 7.2)` would be in first case `T1=int` (provided), `T2=double` (deduced) and in second case `RT=int` (provided), `T1=int, T2=double` (deduced). Content's definition of both methods aren't used to select overload.

Comment: as for me, the second case is suitable, since there's return type conversion for the first one and no conversion at all for the second, isn't it?

Comment: hmmm... return type conversion doesn't play role... then, yes, both calls are equivalent from this point of view